# How to parallel process binary files in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I'm trying to make a function that splits binary file into chunks and uploads

```rb
class ChunksClient < ApiStruct::Client
  # Takes the file, splits it into chunks and uploads each chunk into array of urls
  # in corresponding order
  def upload_chunks(big_file, array_of_urls)
    chunk_size = 5242880
    links.each do |link|
      chunk = object.read(chunk_size)
      upload_chunk(chunk, link)
    end
  end

  def upload_chunk(chunk, link)
    put(path: link, body: chunk, headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/octet-stream' })
  end
end
```

However, doing it one chunk in a time is slow. So I tried to process them in parallel:

```rb
class ChunksClient < ApiStruct::Client
  # Takes the file, splits it into chunks and uploads each chunk into array of urls
  # in corresponding order
  def upload_chunks(big_file, array_of_urls)
    @chunk_size = 5242880
    @index = 0
    @object = object
    threads = []
    links.each do
      threads << Thread.new do
        chunk, index = take_chunk_with_index
        upload_chunk(chunk, links[index])
      end
    end
    threads.each(&:join)
  end

  private

  def upload_chunk(chunk, link)
    put(path: link, body: chunk, headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/octet-stream' })
  end

  def take_chunk_with_index
    index = @index
    chunk = @object.read(@chunk_size)
    @index += 1
    [chunk, index]
  end
end
```

But it puts chunks into random links each time. I could just load the chunks into memory, but that way it would have trouble uploading big files (in gigabytes, for example)

Is there a correct way to process binary files with threads?

Comment: I'm curious: why do you split the file in the first place? Wouldn't it be much easier to just upload the whole file?

Answer (score 0):

You should synchronize your `take_chunk_with_index` method with `Mutex` like so;

```rb
@mutex = Mutex.new

def take_chunk_with_index
  @mutex.synchronize do
    index = @index
    chunk = @object.read(@chunk_size)
    @index += 1
    [chunk, index]
  end
end
```